# complex sqlite update statement efficiency

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I have an in-memory SQLite database that is being created dynamically based on user input using sqlite3 in Python3.9. I have one update statement that is an issue in terms of speed. I have simplified the case to only include the SQLite and not Python.

**TABLES**

The table to be updated is called `West100_1` which contains two id columns: `id` and `pseudo_id`. `pseudo_id` is NULL in most places, and there are a maximum of 4 values for `pseudo_id` where the values for `id` are all the same. All other columns are in the configureation of {taxon]_PL, which in this case are 21 columns. This table can get quite big, upwards of a million rows.

the other tables are:

- `100_1` a map of points with the same `id`s as in `West100_1`, so can also get quite big. Contains columns of the size (`resolution`) of each point which has two possible values, and the associated community `veg_com` (and a number of other columns such as geometry that aren't relevant here).
- `sampling_sites` which contains the name and point geometry (x and y) of sampling sites. Small table, in this case 2 rows
- `vegcom` which contains the names of the vegetation communities and the percentage cover of a taxon in that community. Small table, usually no more than 1000 rows.
- `dist_dir` contains a lookup table of the distance and direction from sampling sites for each `id`. Same number of rows as {map_name}.
- `pseudo_points` contains the same lookup table but for the pseudo points. Very small, usually no more than 40 rows.
- `DistanceLookup` a lookup table containing per plant taxon a weighting value for each possible distance. Fairly big, usually about a quarter of the number of rows of the main table.
- `windrose` a small lookup table with two colums: cardinal direction and weighting. Small, always 8 rows.

**QUERY**

THe query is essentially a mathmatical formula for which the inputs around taken from the various tables. The query needs to be run multiple times, once for each entry in `sampling_sites` (example here being "West") * each entry in `taxa` (example here being Cyperaceae). In this case that means 42 times. The query below is ONE of these queries, but they are otherwise all the same in construction.

```
UPDATE West100_1 SET "Cyperaceae_PL" =
    (0.87 * 
        (SELECT "vegcom_percent" FROM vegcom WHERE "taxon_code" = "Cyperaceae" AND "veg_com" = 
            (SELECT "veg_com" FROM "100_1" WHERE (id = West100_1.id)
            )
        )
        * 
        (CASE WHEN West100_1.pseudo_id NOT NULL THEN 
            (SELECT "Cyperaceae_DW" FROM DistanceLookup WHERE DistanceLookup.distance = 
                (SELECT "distance" FROM pseudo_points WHERE (pseudo_id = West100_1.pseudo_id)
                )
            )
        ELSE 
            (SELECT "Cyperaceae_DW" FROM DistanceLookup WHERE DistanceLookup.distance = 
                (SELECT "distance" FROM dist_dir WHERE (id = West100_1.id) AND (site_name = "West")
                )
            ) 
        END)
    * 
        (SELECT "windrose_weight" FROM windrose WHERE 
            (CASE WHEN West100_1.pseudo_id is NULL THEN 
                ("direction" = 
                    (SELECT "direction" FROM dist_dir WHERE ((id = West100_1.id) AND (site_name = "West"))
                    )
                ) 
            ELSE 
                ("direction" = 
                    (SELECT "direction" FROM pseudo_points WHERE (pseudo_id = West100_1.pseudo_id)
                    )
                ) 
            END)
        )
    )
```

I have applied indices wherever I could think to add them, and that results in this query plan. Unfortunately to avoid an error in the overarching programme earlier on I have to copy all the tables which makes using keys impossible as (I think) there exists no way to copy tables with keys intact.

**QUERY PLAN**

```
 [(4, 0, 0, 'SCAN West100_1'),
 (21, 0, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2'),
 (26, 21, 0, 'SEARCH vegcom USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_vegcom_1 (veg_com=? AND taxon_code=?)'),
 (28, 21, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1'),
 (33, 28, 0, 'SEARCH 100_1 USING INDEX 100_1_idx (id=?)'),
 (57, 0, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 4'),
 (62, 57, 0, 'SEARCH DistanceLookup USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_DistanceLookup_1 (distance=?)'),
 (64, 57, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3'),
 (69, 64, 0, 'SEARCH pseudo_points USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_pseudo_points_1 (pseudo_id=?)'),
 (92, 0, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 6'),
 (97, 92, 0, 'SEARCH DistanceLookup USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_DistanceLookup_1 (distance=?)'),
 (99, 92, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 5'),
 (104, 99, 0, 'SEARCH dist_dir USING INDEX dist_dir_id_name_idx (id=? AND site_name=?)'),
 (128, 0, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 9'),
 (132, 128, 0, 'SCAN windrose'),
 (138, 128, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 7'),
 (143, 138, 0, 'SEARCH dist_dir USING INDEX dist_dir_id_name_idx (id=? AND site_name=?)'),
 (160, 128, 0, 'CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 8'),
 (165, 160, 0, 'SEARCH pseudo_points USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_pseudo_points_1 (pseudo_id=?)')]
```

I am not very proficient at reading the query plans, is there any index that I am missing?

In an example where `West100_1` has 284903 points, the combined 41 queries take ~60 seconds to run, so about 1.5 seconds per query. In the further code this needs to be done many times (more than 1000 times), causing the code to run for about a day  so I would really like to shave off time any way I can.

table examples (top 10 rows):

West100_1 (before filling)

| msa_id | pseudo_id | Alnus_PL | Apiaceae_PL | Ast_lactuceae_PL | Betula_PL | Cerealia_PL | Chenopodiaceae_PL | Corylus_PL | Cyperaceae_PL | Filipendula_PL | Fraxinus_PL | Plantago_PL | Quercus_PL | Ranunculaceae_PL | Rubiaceae_PL | Rumex_PL | Salix_PL | Sambucus_PL | Solidago_PL | Tilia_PL | Urtica_PL | Poaceae_PL | Ulmus_PL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | [NULL] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

100_1

| msa_id | geom_X | geom_Y | veg_com | chance_to_happen | resolution | lidar_su1 | 50m_basin | 2m_basin | 5m_basin | 10m_basin | ESB_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53607 | 456224.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.178999901 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53606 | 456223.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.179999828 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 53609 | 456226.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.209000111 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53608 | 456225.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.196000099 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53603 | 456220.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.175000191 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53602 | 456219.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.169000149 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53605 | 456222.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.188000202 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53604 | 456221.3438 | 412147.5 | Phramitetalia_Fen | 0 | 1 | 4.191999912 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53599 | 456216.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.164000034 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |
| 53598 | 456215.3438 | 412147.5 | Alnus Carr | 0 | 1 | 4.168000221 |  |  |  |  | PEAT |

sampling sites

| site_name | sample_x | sample_y | sample_is_lake | snapped_x | snapped_y | msa_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| West | 456328.7 | 412024.2 | no | 456328.3438 | 412048.5 | 88361 |
| East | 456811.0 | 412150.0 | no | 456811.3438 | 412174.5 | 219294 |

vegcom

| veg_com | taxon_code | vegcom_percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Quercus_woodland | Alnus | 0.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Betula | 1.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Cyperaceae | 0.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Filipendula | 0.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Quercus | 68.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Poaceae | 5.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Rubiaceae | 0.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Salix | 0.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Sambucus | 0.0 |
| Quercus_woodland | Urtica | 0.0 |

dist_dir

| msa_id | site_name | geom_X | geom_Y | distance | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | West | 451594.8438 | 417062.0 | 6895.013016666466 | SE |
| 2 | West | 451644.8438 | 417062.0 | 6860.783810906739 | SE |
| 3 | West | 451694.8438 | 417062.0 | 6826.749189768143 | SE |
| 4 | West | 451744.8438 | 417062.0 | 6792.912078041346 | SE |
| 5 | West | 451794.8438 | 417062.0 | 6759.275441939025 | SE |
| 6 | West | 451844.8438 | 417062.0 | 6725.842289260134 | SE |
| 7 | West | 451894.8438 | 417062.0 | 6692.615669527125 | SE |
| 8 | West | 451944.8438 | 417062.0 | 6659.598674094408 | SE |
| 9 | West | 451994.8438 | 417062.0 | 6626.7944362263115 | SE |
| 10 | West | 452044.8438 | 417062.0 | 6594.206131142701 | SE |

pseudo_points

| pseudo_id | site_name | msa_id | direction | distance | geom_X | geom_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | West | 88361 | NE | 17.67766952966369 | 456353.3438 | 412073.5 |
| 1 | West | 88361 | SE | 17.67766952966369 | 456353.3438 | 412023.5 |
| 2 | West | 88361 | SW | 17.67766952966369 | 456303.3438 | 412023.5 |
| 3 | West | 88361 | NW | 17.67766952966369 | 456303.3438 | 412073.5 |
| 4 | East | 219294 | NE | 17.67766952966369 | 456836.3438 | 412199.5 |
| 5 | East | 219294 | SE | 17.67766952966369 | 456836.3438 | 412149.5 |
| 6 | East | 219294 | SW | 17.67766952966369 | 456786.3438 | 412149.5 |
| 7 | East | 219294 | NW | 17.67766952966369 | 456786.3438 | 412199.5 |

DistanceLookup

| distance | Alnus_DW | Apiaceae_DW | Ast_lactuceae_DW | Betula_DW | Cerealia_DW | Chenopodiaceae_DW | Corylus_DW | Cyperaceae_DW | Filipendula_DW | Fraxinus_DW | Plantago_DW | Quercus_DW | Ranunculaceae_DW | Rubiaceae_DW | Rumex_DW | Salix_DW | Sambucus_DW | Solidago_DW | Tilia_DW | Urtica_DW | Poaceae_DW | Ulmus_DW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6895.013016666466 | 0.001357056 | 0.0005537155 | 0.0003402101 | 0.001235861 | 0.0001178434 | 0.001428499 | 0.001193509 | 0.0007838263 | 0.001206789 | 0.001318041 | 0.001065177 | 0.0007838263 | 0.001536813 | 0.001428499 | 0.001459729 | 0.001318041 | 0.001539254 | 0.001487034 | 0.0008993352 | 0.001305283 | 0.0007838263 | 0.0008993352 |
| 6860.783810906739 | 0.001371135 | 0.0005600131 | 0.0003442246 | 0.001248859 | 0.0001193351 | 0.001443179 | 0.001206113 | 0.0007924783 | 0.001218448 | 0.001331777 | 0.001076586 | 0.0007924783 | 0.001552245 | 0.001443179 | 0.001474663 | 0.001331777 | 0.001554632 | 0.001502182 | 0.0009091354 | 0.001317954 | 0.0007924783 | 0.0009091354 |
| 6826.749189768143 | 0.001385349 | 0.0005663762 | 0.0003482838 | 0.001261984 | 0.0001208443 | 0.001457999 | 0.001218848 | 0.0008012205 | 0.001230209 | 0.001345645 | 0.0010881 | 0.0008012205 | 0.001567817 | 0.001457999 | 0.001489738 | 0.001345645 | 0.001570157 | 0.001517467 | 0.0009190341 | 0.001330739 | 0.0008012205 | 0.0009190341 |
| 6792.912078041346 | 0.001399691 | 0.0005728063 | 0.0003523861 | 0.001275227 | 0.0001223712 | 0.001472964 | 0.001231698 | 0.0008100494 | 0.001242074 | 0.001359637 | 0.001099735 | 0.0008100494 | 0.001583532 | 0.001472964 | 0.001504955 | 0.001359637 | 0.001585819 | 0.001532889 | 0.00092903 | 0.001343638 | 0.0008100494 | 0.00092903 |
| 6759.275441939025 | 0.001414174 | 0.0005793018 | 0.0003565331 | 0.001288603 | 0.0001239155 | 0.001488063 | 0.001244679 | 0.000818966 | 0.001254042 | 0.001373769 | 0.001111473 | 0.000818966 | 0.001599389 | 0.001488063 | 0.001520306 | 0.001373769 | 0.001601627 | 0.001548458 | 0.0009391251 | 0.001356646 | 0.000818966 | 0.0009391251 |
| 6725.842289260134 | 0.001428784 | 0.0005858628 | 0.0003607231 | 0.001302097 | 0.0001254773 | 0.001503292 | 0.001257774 | 0.0008279711 | 0.00126611 | 0.001388032 | 0.001123323 | 0.0008279711 | 0.001615387 | 0.001503292 | 0.001535803 | 0.001388032 | 0.001617571 | 0.001564163 | 0.0009493169 | 0.001369766 | 0.0008279711 | 0.0009493169 |
| 6692.615669527125 | 0.001443527 | 0.0005924889 | 0.000364956 | 0.001315724 | 0.0001270567 | 0.001518666 | 0.00127099 | 0.0008370621 | 0.001278279 | 0.001402418 | 0.001135284 | 0.0008370621 | 0.001631522 | 0.001518666 | 0.001551432 | 0.001402418 | 0.00163365 | 0.001580013 | 0.0009596061 | 0.001382997 | 0.0008370621 | 0.0009596061 |
| 6659.598674094408 | 0.001458402 | 0.0005991799 | 0.0003692319 | 0.001329466 | 0.0001286535 | 0.001534175 | 0.001284326 | 0.0008462387 | 0.001290548 | 0.001416933 | 0.001147356 | 0.0008462387 | 0.001647796 | 0.001534175 | 0.0015672 | 0.001416933 | 0.001649871 | 0.001595997 | 0.0009699912 | 0.001396336 | 0.0008462387 | 0.0009699912 |
| 6626.7944362263115 | 0.001473408 | 0.0006059357 | 0.0003735522 | 0.001343331 | 0.0001302674 | 0.001549814 | 0.001297783 | 0.0008555016 | 0.001302917 | 0.001431577 | 0.001159538 | 0.0008555016 | 0.001664207 | 0.001549814 | 0.001583098 | 0.001431577 | 0.001666225 | 0.001612113 | 0.0009804726 | 0.001409785 | 0.0008555016 | 0.0009804726 |
| 6594.206131142701 | 0.001488537 | 0.0006127558 | 0.0003779133 | 0.001357318 | 0.0001318989 | 0.001565586 | 0.001311349 | 0.0008648502 | 0.001315382 | 0.001446348 | 0.001171829 | 0.0008648502 | 0.001680751 | 0.001565586 | 0.001599138 | 0.001446348 | 0.001682709 | 0.001628366 | 0.0009910476 | 0.001423337 | 0.0008648502 | 0.0009910476 |

windrose

| direction | windrose_weight |
| --- | --- |
| N | 1.0 |
| NE | 1.0 |
| E | 1.0 |
| SE | 10.0 |
| S | 1.0 |
| SW | 1.0 |
| W | 1.0 |
| NW | 1.0 |